# How to get data from a table with a certain prefix?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where the name is like "id,name" and I know the id portion and I need to get all the rows from the table by giving that id. The ID is always unique for the table. I've tried selecting the table out from information_schema.tables and I can get the table selected but then can't figure out how to get the data from it.

Comment: A bit tangential to the core of your question, but if you have a design that relies on dynamically-generated table names within a traditional RDBMS, you have a pretty severe design flaw and your database design doesn’t conform to third normal form (per best practice).

Comment: Which RDBMS? Dom you want a pure SQL solution, or are you using some front end language?  Please edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @Abra, how do you know it's SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking to use `AS` (alias):

```
SELECT test1.id AS id_test1, t2.id AS id_test2 
FROM table1 AS test1
INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 ON (...)
```